# What is that sensor on the Airbus A220?

Tags: feature-identification, sensors, airbus-a220

What is the that sensor in the picture?

[image: Airbus A220 sensors]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's one of the two ice detectors [manufactured by Collins](http://www.airframer.com/aircraft_detail.html?model=CSeries). Below is not precisely the model used by A220, but serves to illustrate the general layout of the unit:

[image: Ice-Detector]

<sub>Image ref: [Collins](https://www.collinsaerospace.com/-/media/project/collinsaerospace/collinsaerospace-website/product-assets/marketing/i/ice-detection/ice-detector-model-0871nd.pdf?rev=66492a2d3da54da190ccdad02005669c)</sub>

From [this Collins fact sheet](https://www.collinsaerospace.com/-/media/project/collinsaerospace/collinsaerospace-website/product-assets/marketing/i/ice-detection/ice-detector-model-0871na.pdf?rev=48bc0a70d3c4468ca995182a052c5d5a), ice detectors

> use a magnetostrictive technology to drive the sensing probe to resonate at its natural frequency. As ice accretes on the probe, a shift in resonance frequency occurs. When the resonance frequency reaches the set point, an ice signal is activated...

Comment: [This picture](http://www.planepics.org/reiseberichte/yul2016/69.jpg) shows the probe more clearly. It looks exactly like the image you show (even if it is not the exact same model).